# Upload file to HDFS in chunks

Tags: ruby, webhdfs

I would like to use the gem 'webhdfs' to upload a file in chunks to HDFS. I see in the documentation there is a create method but I'm not sure how to use that and upload a large file in chunks. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have to chunk it yourself. You can pass a file handle and let the library stream it.

```
file_IO_handle = File.open('/tmp/foo.bin', 'rb')
# Straight from the documentation:
client.create('/path/to/file', file_IO_handle, :overwrite => false, :permission => 0666)
```

Comment: In this case, what is the file_IO_handle?

Comment: Just any file object, like `File.open('/tmp/foo.bin', 'rb')`

Comment: I guess to be more specific, what is rb in this case?

Comment: r for read, b for binary mode. (just to clarify if someone else stumbles here)